# How to convert a JSON string to an image?

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-xe2, datasnap

I have an application that converts an image to a JSON array and I'm saving it into a blob field:

```
function getImage(): String;
var
  memorystream : TMemoryStream;
  jsonArray    : TJSONArray;

begin
  memorystream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  myImage.Picture.Graphic.SaveToStream(memorystream);
  memorystream.Position := 0;

  jsonArray := TJSONArray.Create;
  jsonArray := TDBXJSONTools.StreamToJSON(memorystream, 0, memorystream.Size);

  memorystream.Free;

  Result := jsonArray.ToString;
end;
```

The result of the convertion of a PNG image looks like this:

```
[137,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,0, ... ]
```

This result is stored in a blob field that I get back with this code:

```
stream := TStream.Create;
stream := cdsPesquisa.CreateBlobStream(fieldAux, bmRead);
stream.Position := 0;

jsonArray := TJSONArray.Create;
jsonArray := TDBXJSONTools.StreamToJSON(stream, 0, stream.Size);
```

Here, I have the same JSON string `[137,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,0, ... ]` at the beginning, but I need to convert this JSON array into an image again.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: storing as a json string is going to vastly bloat the storage requirements. e.g. `137` in text form is 3 bytes, v.s. 1 byte if you stored  as a raw 0x89 hex byte.

Comment: It stands to reason that if you're using `TDBXJSONTools.StreamToJSON` to convert to an array to go out, you'd need to reverse that coming back with `TDBXJSONTools.JSONToStream`. But there's no sense in converting it to a JSONArray to store it to a TBlobField and then convert it back, when you can just save the raw data without the conversion in the first place.

Comment: well, I can change this to send a json string instead bytes send with hex, but this isnt my problem. I need to send this string to my server. thanks for replying

Comment: Thanks Ken, but I just using this conversion at first time because I need do pass this string to a SQL because I dont work with clientdataset online.

Comment: @Ken If it looked like I have stolen your answer, sorry. I wrote the code and completely missed all the JSON. And then I saw your comment saying that it is needless.

Comment: @David: No problem. You didn't. I was just posting the comment. :-)

Comment: @Ricardo: Then you need to edit your question and say you're transmitting it to the server. Your question says merely "save in a blobfield". The rest of my comment still applies (about `StreamToJSON` and `JSONToStream`).

Comment: @Ken thanks for helping, I just edit my question ! I would like to know if there is a json function to convert this back ? 
I was think in create a table characters and get bytes from this string and convert it to ASCII..

Answer (score 7):

As suggested by Ken, it's simplest to forget all about JSON and write directly to the blob field.

**Saving**

```
Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
try
  myImage.Picture.Graphic.SaveToStream(Stream);
  Stream.Position := 0;
  fieldAux.LoadFromStream(Stream);
finally
  Stream.Free;
end;
```

**Loading**

```
Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
try
  fieldAux.SaveToStream(Stream);
  Stream.Position := 0;
  myImage.Picture.Graphic.LoadFromStream(Stream);
finally
  Stream.Free;
end;
```

---

You appear insistent in the comments that JSON is what you need. I'm find that a little hard to believe. But anyway, to convert from your JSON array, held in a string, to an image, do this:

```
jsonArray := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(jsonString) as TJSONArray;
try
  Stream := TDBXJSONTools.JSONToStream(jsonArray);
  try
    Stream.Position := 0;
    myImage.Picture.Graphic.LoadFromStream(Stream);
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
finally
  jsonArray.Free;
end;
```

Also, to the best of my knowledge, your code that calls `TDBXJSONTools.StreamToJSON` does not work. It yields an empty JSON array object.

---

Finally, your code was leaking like a sieve. You are under the mis-apprehension that you don't need to free objects that you create. You also are mistakenly instantiating objects and then overwriting the new object with a different object, thus leaking the first. Take a look at how I created objects, and compare with your code. For example:

```
jsonArray := TJSONArray.Create ;
jsonArray := TDBXJSONTools.StreamToJSON( memorystream , 0 , memorystream.Size ) ;
```

Here you instantiate a `TJSONArray` object and store a reference to that object in `jsonArray`. It is your job to free that reference. But you immediately abandon that reference in the next line when you overwrite it with the reference to the new object returned by `StreamToJSON`. Since you never free `jsonArray` at all you leak not one, but two objects.

You do need to brush up your basic understanding of Delphi lifetime management.

Comment: +1. I don't use that class to work with JSON either (I actually don't work with JSON at all), and hadn't gotten around to actually writing code to do the reversal. You beat me to it. :-)

Comment: @David, just a nitpick, I don't know what the `fieldAux` is but most stream implementations reset the stream position to 0 when you call `LoadFromStream`.

Comment: @TLama `fieldAux` is a `TBlobField`.

Comment: @TLama So for the blob field, setting position to zero is not needed?

Comment: @David, at most of the `LoadFromStream` implementations. For instance the `TBlobField.LoadFromStream` calls the ancestor's `TStream.CopyFrom` which resets the input stream position to 0 (at least in Delphi 2009) [at least now; I'm resetting it to 0 for sure too].

Comment: Sorry @Davi, really you are rigth, I did not realize that I did a free the object, I shifted both in the code I just making this mistake. Well you make me see that I was using a StreamToJSON method twice and I didnt setting json array with correctly as below.
  
  jsonArray := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue( myDataSetField.AsString ) as TJSONArray ;
  
All Guys, Thanks for all !

Comment: @Ricardo Does this answer the question then?